# Store "Viewer.Readline" into a string to use for an if/else statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

N00b programmer here...
Trying to store something into a string to use it in an if/else statement...
I'm uploading a .txt file into memory, and parsing text that is inside of it onto the webpage. This is what the content looks like that I am parsing into the webpage

---

.RES B7=121
.RES C12=554
.RES VMAX=4.7μV

---

Only problem with this is that there is stuff in there that has to be included into the .txt file, but I don't wish to parse this stuff (This text I don't wish to parse has no pattern of any sort or anything. It's just words with a few asterisks).
Someone suggested to me to put certain code into a string (*Tried it, and it's not giving me the desired results*) so that I can use that string in an if/else statement, setting the if to say

```
if (string startswith (".RES")
{
//Code that parses
}
else
{
//Code that tell viewer to skip over that line if it doesn't start with ".RES"
}
```

What would you guys suggest? Give me some pointers? Remember, I'm learning this game so suggestions that are easy to read, if you could please.
*Here's my code I'm using*
*C# page*

```
        protected void btnUpld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream theStream = file1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        using (StreamReader viewer = new StreamReader((Stream)file1.PostedFile.InputStream))
        {

            while (viewer.Peek() > 0) //Reads all text lines from imported .txt file that is imported into memory
            {
                String[] parts = viewer.ReadLine().Split(new[] { '=' }); //splits text lines at "="... They suggested I put this into a string to use as in the if/else... Would that be a simple approach?
                String variOutpt = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[0].Substring(".RES ".Length) : String.Empty; //Reads value after skipping over ".RES", before the "=" split
                String valOutpt = parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : String.Empty; //Reads value after the "=" split
                String otput = String.Format("{0}:<input type='text' value='{1}' /><br />", variOutpt, valOutpt); //Sets up format for variOutpt&valOutpt
                rslt.InnerHtml += otput; //Prints it all into a div on my aspx page
            }
        }
    }
```

*Stuff hanging out in my aspx page...*

```
        <asp:FileUpload ID="file1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpld" runat="server" Text="Upload&Display" onclick="btnUpld_Click" />
        <div runat="server" id="rslt" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `String.StartsWith()` is a good idea if that really differentiates all valid lines from the rest.

A more powerful but also more complex way would be using a Regex.

Your code seems to need:

```
while (viewer.Peek() > 0) 
{
    string line = viewer.ReadLine();
    if (! string startswith (".RES")
       continue;

    String[] parts = line .Split('=');  // note simplification   
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks man. Answered my question perfectly... Sometimes the smallest answers are the best